# Generating a CSR fails with 'routines:RSA_sign:digest too big for rsa' - for heroku

Tags: openssl, heroku, rsa

I tried generating a CSR by following [Heroku instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#generate-csr). Specifically

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key
openssl req -nodes -new -key server.key -out server.csr
# input data here
```

I get the following error:

```
140509003069088:error:04075070:rsa routines:RSA_sign:digest too big for rsa key:rsa_sign.c:127:
140509003069088:error:0D0DC006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_sign_ctx:EVP lib:a_sign.c:314:
```

I am using openssl version:

```
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At what point do you get the error? You can omit the second command by simply providing no password. Also, req can also create the key, resulting in a one-liner.

Comment: @sebix Getting the error after the call to `req`. I have virtually zero idea about what I'm doing so I did not want to stray from the path that heroku has suggested

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, that was caused by placing 256 in the commands where the key size is required. Worked typing 1024, in yours is 2048

Answer (score 0):

While this is very interesting, I just ended up switching to a different machine (same openssl version). Worked like a charm. Also worked on 2 others I've tried.

So solution: **switch to another machine**.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when I mistyped the key length for a previous command.
e.g., '409' bits instead of '4096' -

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 409
openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
(error)
```

vs.

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 4096
openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
(success)
```

So maybe try backing up a few steps and make sure all your previous commands were entered correctly.